# How do I determine which form is submitted and process different submission function using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm new to jquery and am trying to alter an existing page template that uses jquery for a contact form to handle form validation. If the form elements are valid, it submits the data elements to a page that processes it (sends an email). What I'm trying to do is to alter the existing code as I have two additional forms that are on the same page. Essentially, one form is for generating the contact email, a second form contains a couple of elements for submitting a donation request to paypal, and a third form will be similar to the contact email but will contain a few other form elements to provide more info than the standard contact form.

There are a couple of pieces to the puzzle. First, there is a file called script.js which contains the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hover

    $('#menu> li > a strong').css({opacity:0})

    $('#menu > li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('> a strong').stop().animate({opacity:1})             
    }, function(){
        if  (!$(this).hasClass('active')&&!$(this).hasClass('sfHover')) {
            $(this).find('> a strong').stop().animate({opacity:0})             
        }
    })

    $('.list1 .img_act').css({opacity:0, display:'none'})

    $('.list1 li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.img_act').css({display:'block'}).stop().animate({opacity:1}, function(){$(this).css({opacity:'none'})})                        
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.img_act').stop().animate({opacity:0}, function(){$(this).css({display:'none'})})                       
    })

    $("a[data-type^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'facebook',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: false});
        $('.lightbox-image').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.play').stop().animate({width:71, height:71, marginTop:-35, marginLeft:-35})
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('.play').stop().animate({width:51, height:51, marginTop:-25, marginLeft:-25})
        })



    $('ul#menu').superfish({
      delay:       600,
      animation:   {height:'show'},
      speed:       600,
      autoArrows:  false,
      dropShadows: false
    });

        //gallery 
    $("#gallery1").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev",
            mouseWheel: true,
            visible: 3,
            vertical: true,
            speed: 600,
            easing: 'easeOutCirc'
    });

    $('#gallery1 a').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({opacity:0.7})                           
    },function(){
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({opacity:1})                         
    })


 });
$(window).load(function() { 
    //bg animate

    $('#bgStretch').bgStretch({
            align:'leftTop',
            navigs:$('#pagination').navigs()
        })
        .sImg({
            spinner:$('.spinner').css({opacity:.7}).hide()
    })

    $('#pagination li').eq(0).addClass('active');

    // scroll
    $('.scroll').cScroll({
        duration:700,
        step:63,
        trackCl:'track',
        shuttleCl:'shuttle'
    })

    // contact form
    $('#ContactForm').forms({
        ownerEmail:'#'
    })  

        // other form
    $('#OtherForm').forms({
        ownerEmail:'#'
    })  

        // contact form
    $('#DonateForm').forms({
        ownerEmail:'#'
    })  

        // contact form
    $('#JoinForm').forms({
        ownerEmail:'#'
    })  

    //content switch
    var content=$('#content'),
        nav=$('.menu');
    nav.navs({
        useHash:true
    })  
    nav.navs(function(n, _){
        content.cont_sw(n);
        $('#menu > li').not('.sfHover').find('>a strong').stop().animate({opacity:0})
        if (_.n!=-1) {
            $('#menu > li').eq(_.n).find('>a strong').stop().animate({opacity:1})
        }
        if (_.n==0) {
            $('#content').stop().animate({height:310})
        } else {
            $('#content').stop().animate({height:510})
        }
    })
    content.cont_sw({
        showFu:function(){
            var _=this          
            $.when(_.li).then(function(){
                _.next.css({display:'block', left:-1500}).stop().animate({left:0},600, function(){

                }); 
            });
        },
        hideFu:function(){
            var _=this
            _.li.stop().animate({left:2000},600, function(){
                _.li.css({display:'none'})
            })
        },
        preFu:function(){
            var _=this
            _.li.css({position:'absolute', display:'none'});
        }
    })
    nav.navs(0);

    var h_cont=950;
    function centre() {
        var h=$(window).height();
        if (h>h_cont) {
            m_top=~~(h-h_cont)/2+12;
        } else {
            m_top=12;
        }
        $('#content').stop().animate({marginTop:m_top})
    }
    centre();
    $(window).resize(centre);

})
```

Then there is a separate file called forms.js which contains the code for the form validation and submission. That's what I'm trying to work with to be able to have my other two forms validated and submitted. Here is the full code for the forms.js (rather than the snippet in the original post):

```
    (function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        forms:function(opt){
            if(opt===undefined)
                opt={}
            this.each(function(){
                var th=$(this),
                    data=th.data('forms'),
                    _={
                        errorCl:'error',
                        emptyCl:'empty',
                        invalidCl:'invalid',
                        successCl:'success',
                        successShow:'4000',
                        mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                        ownerEmail:'support@guardlex.com',
                        stripHTML:true,
                        smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                        targets:'input,textarea',
                        controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                        validate:true,
                        rx:{
                            ".employer":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                            ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                            ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                            ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                            ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                            ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                            ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                        },
                        preFu:function(){
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var label=$(this),
                                    inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                    defVal=inp.attr('value'),
                                    trueVal=(function(){
                                                var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                                return tmp
                                            })()

                                trueVal!=defVal
                                    &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                                label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                                inp
                                    .bind('focus',function(){
                                        inp.val()==defVal
                                            &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                    })
                                    .bind('blur',function(){
                                        !inp.val()
                                            ?inp.val(defVal)                                        
                                            :(_.isValid(label)
                                                ?_.showErrorFu(label)
                                                :_.hideErrorFu(label)),
                                            (_.isEmpty(label)
                                                ?_.showEmptyFu(label)
                                                :_.hideEmptyFu(label))
                                    })
                                    .bind('keyup',function(){
                                        label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                            &&_.isValid(label)
                                                ?_.showErrorFu(label)
                                                :_.hideErrorFu(label)
                                    })
                                label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                            })
                            _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                        },
                        isValid:function(el){
                            var ret=true,
                                empt=_.isEmpty(el)
                            if(empt)
                                ret=false,
                                el.addClass(_.invalidCl)
                            else
                                $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                                    if(el.is(k))
                                        d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())
                                            ?(el.removeClass(_.invalidCl),ret=false)
                                            :el.addClass(_.invalidCl)
                                })
                            return ret
                        },
                        isEmpty:function(el){
                            var tmp
                            return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                        },
                        validateFu:function(){                          
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)                              
                                _.isEmpty(th)
                                    ?_.showEmptyFu(th)
                                    :_.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                _.isValid(th)
                                    ?_.showErrorFu(th)
                                    :_.hideErrorFu(th)
                            })
                        },
                        submitFu:function(){
                            _.validateFu()
                            var id=$(this).attr('id');
                            var action=$(this).attr('action');

                            if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                    data:{
                                        name:$('.name input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        email:$('.email input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        phone:$('.phone input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        fax:$('.fax input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        state:$('.state input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        message:$('.message textarea',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                        owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                        stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                    },
                                    success: function(){
                                        _.showFu()
                                    }
                                })          
                        },
                        showFu:function(){
                            _.success.slideDown(function(){
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    _.success.slideUp()
                                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                                },_.successShow)
                            })
                        },
                        controlsFu:function(){
                            $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)
                                th
                                    .bind('click',function(){
                                        _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                        return false
                                    })
                            })
                        },
                        showErrorFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                        },
                        hideErrorFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                        },
                        showEmptyFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                            _.hideErrorFu(label)
                        },
                        hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                            label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                        },
                        init:function(){
                            _.form=this
                            _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                            _.preFu()

                            _.controlsFu()

                            _.form
                                .bind('submit',function(){
                                    if(_.validate)
                                        _.submitFu()
                                    else
                                        _.form[0].submit()
                                    return false
                                })
                                .bind('reset',function(){
                                    _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                    _.labels.each(function(){
                                        var th=$(this)
                                        _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                        _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                    })
                                })
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        }
                    }
                if(!data)
                    (typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(_,opt):_).init.call(th),
                    th.data({cScroll:_}),
                    data=_
                else
                    _=typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(data,opt):data
            })
            return this
        }
    })
})(jQuery)
```

Most of this was already included in my page template and works fine. I added the following in the script.js file for the two additional forms

```
// Donate form
$('#DonateForm').forms({
    ownerEmail:'#'
})  

    // join form
$('#JoinForm').forms({
    ownerEmail:'#'
})
```

I have them working from a validation standpoint. That is to say, they seem to behave properly in the same manner as the original contact form. If you click the button or leave focus of an element you get user feedback indicating the form element is required, for example. But I can't quite figure out how to get them submitted.

It seems to me the original code in the forms.js was specifically written to submit the contact form. My first thought was to somehow add an additional evaluation on the form name, with each having it's own url value and set of data values pulled from the form. I just am not sure how to do that being new to jquery. As it stands, my other forms seem to get the validation but nothing happens when I hit the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use more easily

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var action=$(this).attr('action');
    if(id=='some_id')
    {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url:action,
           data:{...},
           success: function(){...}  
       });
    }

    if(id=='something_else')
    {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url:action,
           data:{...},
           success: function(){...}  
        });
    }
});
```

Put this code snippet inside $(document).ready(function(){...}) and give an unique id to each form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is the kind of thing I was thinking of originally. However, that doesn't quite fit into the existing code. I've modified the original post to include the complete code I'm working with. If I implemented this as is, I'm afraid I'd be losing the existing validation code that is working.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Name your forms so you can easily retrieve them

```
//example
<form id="joebob" name="jimbob" ...
// in jquery can be called dynamically as:
$("#joebob")
//or
$("form[name=jimbob]")
//or you can create one dnamically
var frmJoeBob = $("<form />").attr({ id: "joebob", action: "#smartUrl" });
```

Step two: I **strongly** suggest you go [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and add this plugin to your library.

- Simply download the js and add it to your header AFTER the jquery script call.
- What it does is allow an extremely easy way of *ajaxing* your forms so you can have far more control over what they do and when they do it.

> Example usage

```
// first establish a set of option in object style
var formAjaxOptions = {
    target: $("#SomeOutpuEle"),  //  this is where return text will be displayed on complete
    beforeSubmit: function (formData, jqForm, options) { 
        /* Here you can preform work such as form validation before 
        the form is submitted. return false; to stop the form from 
        being submitted. */ 
    },
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $formresponseText, statusText, xhr, $form) { 
        /* Here you can preform work if the ajax call was successful, 
        this doesn't mean the serverside didn't have failures, though.  
        This simply means the ajax call is complete. console.log the 
        vars to get more information on them or see the docs.  */ 
    }
}

// then ajax your form using the plugin with these options as such:
$("#joebob").ajaxForm(formAjaxOptions);

// then simply grab anything you wanna use as a button and set a click event to submit your form
$("span.someButtonAsaSpan").click(function(e) {
    $("#joebob").submit();
});
```

See how easy that was?
One more note, the options object can also be used (in this plugin) to submit jQuery.ajax options, so once you get more of a hang of what's going on, you can fully customize it however you please!

Comment: Thanks for the quick lesson in referencing form names for starters. I typically wouldn't jump into trying to edit established code without having a better idea of the language but I don't have the luxury of time to start from the beginning. I will also look into the plugin you referenced and see how I might use it in the future. I was just hoping not to completely rewrite the existing form capabilities, so would like to be able to figure out how to work within the confines of the code I already have. I've posted the full code to the original questions. Thanks for the response!